# Как сделать что-бы правильно сжималось фото профиля

Tags: python, django

### models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    avatar = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_images')
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save()
        img = Image.open(self.avatar.path)
        if img.height > 900 or img.width > 900:
            new_img = (900, 900)
            img.thumbnail(new_img)
            img.save(self.avatar.path)
```

### forms.py

```
class ProfilavaForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('avatar',)
        widgets = {
            'avatar': forms.FileInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control form-control-sm'})
        }
```

### views.py

```
    if 'editimage' in request.POST:
        profil_red = ProfilavaForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.profile)
        if profil_red.is_valid:
            Avacomments.objects.filter(to_user_com=request.user.profile).delete()
            Avalikes.objects.filter(to_user_com=request.user.profile).delete()
            profil_red.save()
        return redirect('mprofil')
```

### Шаблон

```
<div class="avatar">
    <img class="main_photos" src="{{ profil.avatar.url | default:'media/default.jpg' }} " width="230" height="285" alt="lorem"  class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModals">
</div>
```

У меня есть мой профиль и я могу добавить фото профиля , я могу его открыть для просмотра в полном размере при открытии отображается как нужно полный размер , но когда оно просто отображается на странице профиля оно как бы сжимается по ширине и изображение становится как бы сплюснуто по ширине как сделать что бы края обрезались что бы не было искажения. Возможно есть какие то плагины что бы пользователь сам мог обрезать фото как ему нужно я бы почитал документацию

Comment: Нужно стили подправить, у вас жестко назначена высота и ширина изображения, из-за чего и изображение растягивается/сужается

Answer (score 0):

Это нужно подправить в стилях, как я описал в комментарии. Сужение или растяжение изображения происходит из-за жесткого назначения ширины и высоты тегу `<img>`.

Это можно исправить, если контейнеру (блоку `.avatar`) задать нужные размеры (230x285), а самому изображению проставить `object-fit: cover`, и центральное позиционирование `object-position: center`:

```css
.avatar {
  width: 230px;
  height: 285px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.avatar img {
  max-width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="avatar">
  <img class="main_photos" src="https://i.pravatar.cc/300" alt="lorem" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModals">
</div>
```